# Image processing (Matlab): index exceeds the matrix dimensions

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

well, I am new to matlab programming and I have been battling on the indexing issues. I am currently working on image processing which so far drive me crazy. anyways, lets jump to the questions. 
I have the following code

```
perm=randperm(size(X,2));
CX=X(:,perm(1:nclus));
```

I tried to run the code but it triggers an error saying " Index exceeds the matrix dimensions. To my humble knowledge I think it is because the `(:,perm(1:nclus))` is higher than the matrix dimensions. I would like to know how can i solve this problem.

Note that X: is the input points in the columns 
         nclus: number of clusters.

I highly appreciate if you guys clarify to me the error cause and the possible solution for it.

Thank you

Sami

Comment: How you define size of X? E.g., what number of columns in X matrix?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Danil, X is the input points in the columns in the images that are used as a training data.

Comment: Are you certain that nclus <= size(X, 2) ?

Comment: Yes the number of clusters are less or equal to the size of 2 dimensional matrix (x).. Thank you Dennis

Answer (score 1):

Guessing that you just want to get `nclus` random columns from a 2 dimensional matrix `X`, try this:

```
perm=randperm(size(X,2));
CX=X(:,perm<=nclus);
```

The error that you experience should not come from `X` being called with too many dimensions, it is probably because the dimensions of perm are exceeded. Try running this line by line:

```
perm = randperm(size(X,2)); %Should be ok
idx = perm(1:nclus); %Probably fails
X(:,idx)
```

Comment: Dennis, Thank you and you really got the points but if you have a time can you please explain to me briefly why it exceeds the matrix dimensions. Just want to know a different view. Thank you

Comment: @user2040072 I have updated my answer with a guess of what the problem is, if it is not this please give the variable sizes right before the error occurs.

Comment: Your first answer works perfectly. I was lacking to interpretation of the error occurrence but thank you you did give a precise explanation. however, I am having this problem. "Undefined function or method 'vgg_kmiter'
for input arguments of type 'double'. is it because the input arguments are defined as integers? or this something behind

Comment: @user2040072 That is not within the scope of this question, however you can ofcourse ask a separate question. Just make sure to try and include relevant information.